What would be the probability of each card being $1$ out of the $40$ identical cards, if a person draws $7$ cards?
A friend of mine had asked how would she go about calculating the probability of drawing a certain number of cards in hand. There are $100$ cards in the deck and $40$ cards are identical. What would be the probability of each card being $1$ out of the $40$ identical cards, if she draws $7$ cards? Note, we are not sampling without replacement because we have a deck that is depleted with each draw.
Also, how would she calculate from the same $7$ card draw the probability of having $3$ of the desired cards? Order does not matter again.
My attempt
For the first question:
$$P(\text{1 out of the 40 identical cards, if she draws 7 cards})=\frac{\binom{40}{7}\binom{60}{0}}{\binom{100}{7}}\approx0.0011646$$
For the second question:
$$P(\text{3 out of the 40 identical cards, if she draws 7 cards})=\frac{\binom{40}{3}\binom{60}{4}}{\binom{100}{7}}\approx0.3009723$$
However, I'm unsure about my solution for question 2. Would I be correct here?

Saying that "we are not sampling without replacement", a double negative, would mean that we are sampling with replacement if we took it literally.  If instead we are drawing without replacement, your computations are correct.

In your first calculation, you calculated the probability of selecting $7$ (not $1$) of the $40$ identical cards when $7$ cards are drawn from the deck without replacement.  In your second calculation, you calculated the probability of selecting exactly $3$ of the $40$ identical cards when $7$ cards are drawn from the deck without replacement.
